# Trae las cantidades y valores de acuerdo al lugar de entrega

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un sistema de gestión de comercio electrónico del cual necesito traer los siguientes resultados:

```
Ubicacion   | Número de ventas por ubicación | Valor total por ubicación
  
Ubicacion 1 |              10                |        141.00

Ubicacion 2 |              11                |        123.10  

Ubicacion 3 |              12                |        165.00
```

Estos datos están en 4 tablas. Son ellas:

**tb_users** (Tabla para registro de usuarios)

```
user_id | user_name | user_address 
 
   1    |    Jose   |     33
```

**tb_address** (Tabla para el registro de la dirección del usuario. Puede registrar más de una dirección.)

```
address_id | address_id_user | address_name

   33      |       1         |  {address de usuário}
```

**tb_cart** (Mesa de carrito de compras. El campo cart_address es el ID de la dirección, ya que el usuario puede tener más de 1 dirección registrada y elegir una de ellas para la entrega.)

```
cart_id   |   cart_id_user   |  cart_address

   1      |        1         |      33
```

**tb_order_status** (Estado de la compra que se divide en: Abierta (A), Pago Realizado (P), En Ruta (R) y Finalizada (F). Cada vez que cambia el estado, el estado anterior toma el valor 0 y el nuevo toma el valor 1.)

```
status_id | status_id_user | status_order | status_value

    1     |        1      |       F       |      1
```

Intenté la siguiente consulta, pero no trajo el resultado esperado:

```
// Tabla para almacenar los lugares de entrega registrados por el administrador de comercio electrónico.
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM pd_locations
                                         ORDER BY location_name ASC;");

while($pd = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)
{
   $sqlA = mysqli_query($this->conexao, "SELECT *, SUM(C.cart_value_total) AS VTotal FROM pd_address A
                                 INNER JOIN pd_cart C
                                         ON A.address_id_user = C.cart_id_user
                                 INNER JOIN pd_order_status S
                                         ON S.status_user_id = C.cart_id_user
                                      WHERE S.status_order = 'F'
                                        AND S.status_value = 1
                                        AND A.address_district = '".$pd->location_name."'
                                   GROUP BY S.status_id");   
$pdA = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlA);
echo "Ubicación: " .$pd->location_name. " | Número de ventas por ubicación: " .mysqli_num_rows($sqlA). " | Valor total por ubicación: " .$pdA->VTotal."<br>";
}
```

¿Cómo puedo traer las cantidades y valores según el lugar de entrega?

Comment: Consultas: ¿Necesitas mostrar cuantos productos van a una dirección específica? Si es si, te estaría faltando incluir la tabla con el detalle de los productos del carro. ¿Que tiene que ver la tabla `pd_locations`? Me da la sensación que son las direcciones de los depósitos de la empresa. ¿El cliente puede modificar las direcciones en cualquier momento? Si es si, ¿has pensado lo caótico que esto podría resultar a la hora de saber a donde se envían las cosas?

Comment: Hola marcos. La información solo se pasará arriba. De hecho, la ubicación no se puede cambiar, pero se puede incluir una nueva dirección.